# Can we setup VPC Peering without the use of Internet Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, vpc

I Was trying out a VPC peering exercise and it did not work without the use of Internet Gateway, is there any way to peer VPCs without the use of the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work without the use of Internet Gateway"? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

VPC Peering is **totally independent** from an Internet Gateway.

An **Internet Gateway** provides connectivity between a VPC and the Internet.

**VPC Peering** provides connectivity between two VPCs.